# angularx-social-login - GetAccessToken prompting sign in pop up again

Tags: angular, angular-social-login

I have integrated Google sing in using **angularx-social-login**  in angular 16 app,
able to get the userInfo using

```
this.authService.authState.subscribe((user) => { this.user = user; this.loggedIn = (user != null); });
```

but I need accessToken to pass to resource server and login pop up is prompting again if i try to retrieve access token using

```
getAccessToken(): void { this.authService.getAccessToken(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID).then(accessToken => this.accessToken = accessToken); }
```

Is there a way i can retrieve accessToken without 2 prompts for UserInfo and access token